# Dynamically update RadioButtonBar

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I want to create two `RadioButtonBar` objects that offer choices which are dynamically updated by a `CheckboxBar`. I also need to prevent them from having the same value. I got this far.

My Problem : When the currently selected button of a `RadioButtonBar` has its value updated through the `CheckboxBar`, it becomes de-selected. In other words, the value of the `RadioButtonBar` is updated, but not the value of the variable controlled by it.

I provide a toy example here, but in my real situation, I have many more dynamic lists and buttons. Hence, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require each `dList` or `dRadio` to perform a long list of checks to determine what needs to be updated.

```
DynamicModule[{dList1 = {a}, dList2 = {d}, dList3 = {g}, dRadio1, dRadio2},
 dRadio1=dList1;
 dRadio2=dList2;

 Grid[{

   {"List 1:", CheckboxBar[Dynamic[dList1], {a, b, c}]},
   {"List 2:", CheckboxBar[Dynamic[dList2], {d, e, f}]},
   {"List 3:", CheckboxBar[Dynamic[dList3], {g, h, i}]},

   {"Radio 1:", Dynamic[RadioButtonBar[
      Dynamic[dRadio1, {(If[# == dRadio2, dRadio2 = dRadio1]) &, Automatic}],
      {dList1, dList2, dList3}]]},
   {"Radio 2:", Dynamic[RadioButtonBar[
      Dynamic[dRadio2, {(If[# == dRadio1, dRadio1 = dRadio2]) &, Automatic}], 
      {dList1, dList2, dList3}]]},
   {Dynamic[dRadio1]},
   {Dynamic[dRadio2]}}]]
```

Comment: Could you provide an output you'd expect with some arbitrary input?

Comment: Sure! if you use the code as provided, the first RadioButtonBar should have the first choice `{a}` selected. If you change dList1 to be `{a,b}` through the CheckboxBar, the value of the RadioButtonBar should update (as it does) and the first choice should still be selected.
EDITED TO REFLECT CODE CHANGE.

Comment: So, the problem is that it simply de-selects the value in your `RadioButtonBars` ? What about those `dRadio1` and `dRadio2` do they need to also update? What would they update to?

Comment: They would need to update to the new value of the list they had previously selected. If `dRadio1 = dList1` and `dList1` changes, `dRadio1` should update so that `dRadio1 = dList1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your code work in the described way by simply changing the [`RadioButtonBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RadioButtonBar.html) input to a `{val1 -> labl1, ...}` form.

```
DynamicModule[{dList1 = {a}, dList2 = {d}, dList3 = {g}, dRadio1, dRadio2},
 dRadio1 = 1;
 dRadio2 = 2;
 Grid[{
   {"List 1:", CheckboxBar[Dynamic[dList1], {a, b, c}]},
   {"List 2:", CheckboxBar[Dynamic[dList2], {d, e, f}]},
   {"List 3:", CheckboxBar[Dynamic[dList3], {g, h, i}]}, {"Radio 1:", 
    Dynamic[RadioButtonBar[
      Dynamic[dRadio1, {(If[# == dRadio2, dRadio2 = dRadio1]) &, 
        Automatic}], {1 -> dList1, 2 -> dList2, 
       3 -> dList3}]]}, {"Radio 2:", 
    Dynamic[RadioButtonBar[
      Dynamic[dRadio2, {(If[# == dRadio1, dRadio1 = dRadio2]) &, 
        Automatic}], {1 -> dList1, 2 -> dList2, 3 -> dList3}]]},
   {Dynamic[{dList1, dList2, dList3}[[dRadio1]]]},
   {Dynamic[{dList1, dList2, dList3}[[dRadio2]]]}}]]
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! Are you able to explain why the integer values get updated, but not the variable ones?

Comment: @Lokdal For example, when `dList1` is changed by the `CheckboxBar`, then `dRadio1` stays the same. In my code the value of `dRadio1` still matches its previous value and only the label is changed. In your code, as `dList1` is changed, the value of `dRadio1` no longer matches any of the `{dList1, dList2, dList3}`. In other word if `dRadio1` matched `dList1` (first radio button) before changing `dList1`, it doesn't match it after changing `dList1`. Its like having `RadioButtonBar[0, {1, 2, 3}]` now. Changing labels don't matter.